# Using jquery to process actions which require passing PHP variables within MVC framework

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter, variables

I am using codeigniter. What i want to achieve is as follows.

I am on a page /profile/username (Controller profile, function username).
This function loads a view which has a submit button.

```
<input type=submit value=apple>
```

I then have a jquery file which has ajax processing such that when the submit button is clicked /profile/process_click (a private function) is called with $.post.

The function process_click in the controller profile calls a method function which inserts the value of the submit button into the database (in this case 'apple'). Alongside this function needs to insert the username of the person on whos profile the link was clicked (in this case 'username').

So.. my question is, how do I pass username from my profile controller to my jquery file such that it can be passed to process_click by $.post?

I need a secure and safe and ideally not resource intensive way to do this..

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, the process_click function cannot be private or you won't be able to call it via Ajax.

Jquery post method has a callback function which is called when the PHP script returns an answer, so in your js file do:

```
var userData = $("#form1").serialize();
$.post('http://localhost/profile/process_click',userData, function(data) {
  //some code that handles data returned from php
});
```

in the php script:

```
public function process_data(){
$userName = $_POST['userName'];//or whatever the input name is
...//do some processing
echo $username;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What i want to do however is pass an extra value TO jquery.. so when i click my submit button jquery gets its name. I then want to pass this name AND the profile owners name via jquery to my processing script. How do i get the owners name from my initial controller?

Comment: You need to make a separate ajax call to that controller, then in the callback make another ajax call with the data you got from it.

Comment: Then get is just getting overly complex.
So I am accessing profile/thomas which loads my view. I click a link that has a jquery action associated with it. I then want to call profile/process_click and put 'thomas' into the database. There must be some way of passing this..

Answer (score 1):

i assume all of us would like to help but your question is not understandable, i think this is the reason you have received one answer only. Please edit and explain your problem in a wilder context. Don't save words, and use reference properly. for example, what is to **'jquery file'** ??? what is to pass value to jquery? i assume you refer to javascript variable, and **jquery $.ajax{}** *call*, but can't be sure. can you be more oriented in your description. i also assume your english is much better than mine according to your residence so it shouldn't be an issue for you.

i can try and post back if you fix,
thanks and goodluck

Comment: I have tried to clarify where possible.. but i cant really explain it any more.. I have explained my problem in quite a bit of detail :)